# The output window in vs code is not editable, so how we can type the input when the program asks for it?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

[The Error is shown when I input anything in the output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lhu4.png)

Comment: Your answer is in the question: you want to **input** in the **output** window.

Comment: If you see the screenshot attached you'll see that the output window is asking for the input but we cannot input anything

Comment: Your question is currently very low quality. It doesn't contain any code, no version of VS Code you are using, it's tagged 'java' but your code is Python. Please improve it. Add your code, which keyboard shortcut are you using to run your code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the name implies, output window is only for displaying output. It seems that you're using VSCode Coderunner extension, which by default runs program in output window.

To change it to terminal, simply put :

```
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

In your VSCode User Settings (shortcut: `Ctrl` + `,`).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: it did not work on my case. running a win11 VS code 1.74 and code runner 0.11.8

Answer (score 5):

In general, this problem seems to occur in code runner. But when I was Doing settings according to the upper Most Upvoted Answer, I was not able to edit Json File Correctly as It's showing some error. So, If this is the case, You can do this too.

**GO TO VS CODE SETTINGS.**

**IN USER SEARCH BAR, Type CODE RUNNER TERMINAL**

**Now, Check the option of Run in Terminal. Voila!! Good To Go!**

[Solution Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aezdy.png)

Comment: Awesome! This is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Type the input in the console, not the output window.

Comment: I can manually run the program through the console, but that's not what I'm asking for. My question was that the keyboard shortcut allows me to run the program in the output window itself without using the console. So is there any way I can use the same window to input my variables.

Comment: No, you cannot input in the output window. However, there probably is a console integrated into VS Code that you can activate with a keyboard shortcut or a simple click. It might be called Terminal or Debug Console (I have never worked with VS Code).

Answer (score 0):

you cant input anything in output window.
if you want make any change or edit in output section you should first do debug in console box and then you can make any change you want

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcut command Shift + Ctrl + X to bring out the extensions side bar,
Now in the search extensions in market place entry input "@installed code runner",
Make sure you have installed code runner extension (If you haven't do that now),
Next right click on the extension and select extension settings,
Scroll down to  run in terminal, finally select the check button.
That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The output window is only for outputs. Use your terminal for input-based code.

Answer (score 0):

To get output in terminal of vscode :
step1:
Click Ctrl+, or open the settings
step2:
search for code runner
step3:
turn on the Run in terminal checkbox[screenshot is included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEHpG.png)

Answer (score 0):

it seems you're using Code Runner extension:
so the solution is to go to settings in vscode and search "run in terminal" code runner option and enable it.[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3uA2.png) 
now code runner will run in vscode terminal and every thing will work great

Comment: This was already proposed as accepted answer