# Execution of code stuck on running in VSCode

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

So I have preinstalled extension like 'Code Runner' and 'C/C++' in Vscode.

The problem I am facing is in running a code which gets stuck on running :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //program to convert minutes into years and days
    int min = 0;
    double yrs = 0.0;
    double days = 0.0;
    double min_in_yr = 0;
    printf("Enter the nmuber of minutes: ");

    //get input from the user
    scanf("%d", &min);

    //calculation
    min_in_yr = (60 * 24 * 365);


    yrs = (min / min_in_yr);
    days = (yrs * 365);

    printf("%d minutes is approx %f years and %f days\n", min, yrs, days);



    return 0;
}
```

There is no problem with the code as it seems to be running fine on CodeBlocks.

Also I tried executing a simple hello world program which seemed to be executed perfectly on Vscode in 1.8 s.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine. There must be a problem with your configuration or with the Code Runner Extension. Did you pay attention to the Configuration section of the extension?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük I don't know about any configuration problem as whatever I did were from tutorials.If I enable the code to run in terminal of Vscode it works whereas in output section it gets stuck on running.

Comment: @TMK  I checked in my system, it is working fine. Can tell us the error, you are getting?

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula In the output section of the panel its stuck on running and If I try to execute it from the terminal it works fine.I had to enable the terminal option in settings for it to work.Are you able to run on Output section in the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The output window in vs code is not editable, so how we can type the input when the program asks for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047167/the-output-window-in-vs-code-is-not-editable-so-how-we-can-type-the-input-when)

Answer (score 4):

So I looked up and found a solution for this problem.May it helps other beginners who get stuck doing this on Vscode.

So the problem is actually with the `scanf` function which seems to be not compatible with **OUTPUT** section of the output panel.I don't know the reason for this but I found a alternate way to do this.

Just make your code run in the terminal instead.

To do this:

1.Make sure you have code runner extension installed

2.Goto **File>Preferences>Settings>Extensions>Run Code configuration** and under that scroll down to search for **Code Runner:Run in Terminal** and check that option.If you are not able to find that search in settings for text in bold and you find

3.That's it.Run your code and it will automatically be executed in the terminal

Comment: That was what i did, compile and run it in the terminal.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük For me it by default ran in the output tab so I had to enable run from terminal option in the vscode settings

Comment: Possible duplicate    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047167/the-output-window-in-vs-code-is-not-editable-so-how-we-can-type-the-input-when

Comment: @TMK You can give input to the program, in terminal only, not in output console. Output window is only for displaying output.